# In this case, is there a different augmentation for each epoch?

Tags: torch, torchvision, data-augmentation

I want different augmentation to be applied to each epoch
Below is part of my training code

```
for epoch in range(100):
  for i, data in enumerate(train_dataset):
    #training code
```

And DataLoader's getitem code includes

```
torchvision.transforms([transforms.RandomApply(transforms = [torchvision.transforms.ColorJitter(brightness=0.9, hue=0.3),
torchvision.transfroms.GaussianBlur(3,5)], p=0.5)])
```

According to the above code, is there a possibility that Gaussian blur will be applied to the first epoch and colorJitter will be applied to the second epoch?
Or does the same augmentation apply to all epochs?

Answer (score 0):

You have the same augmentation applied to each epoch, more precisely it is:

For each batch:

- with a probability of 0.5: apply `ColorJitter` and `GaussianBlurr` and return transformed batch
- with a probability of 0.5: do nothing and return batch as is

Comment: Then which batches might have augmentation applied and which ones might not?